# Is Frederic 21 or 22 in "Pirates of Penzance"?

Tags: gilbert-and-sullivan, the-pirates-of-penzance

As we discover in act 2, Frederic has "lived twenty-one years" or "Years twenty-one I’ve been alive". Yet in the opening chorus it states:

> Two and twenty, now he’s rising,

So what's going on here? Seems unlikely this is an oversight given that this is at the heart of the plot.

Is this meant as "completed 21 years and now on course for 22"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word *rising* in this verse is an adjective meaning, per OED:

> Of a horse or (in extended use) of a person: approaching (a specified age)

The OED also gives examples of this usage:

> 1853   ‘C. Bede’ *Adventures Mr. Verdant Green* i. 7:   'Mr. Verdant Green was (in stable language) ‘rising’ sixteen.'
>
> 1920   E. H. Coleridge *Life Thomas Coutts* I. 22:   'His old companion, then rising fifteen, writes to him from the old home.'

Re-ordering the line to a less poetic format gives us

> Now he's rising twenty-two.

So you are correct that he has 'completed 21 years and now on course for 22'.

Comment: I've also heard this in the context of students during summer break:
"What year are you?" "I'm a rising sophomore" <- they completed freshman year, and are going to be a sophomore in the fall.

Comment: This use of "rising (age)" is similar to the phrase "going on (age)" as in "sixteen going on seventeen" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwK_WOXjfc0

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: It does seem contradictory. However, your interpretation doesn't fit the context of that first song. It's much more likely that "Two and twenty" refers to the *age-year* he's in: having turned 21, he's now (by definition) in his 22nd year.**

### Explanation

If I understand you correctly, you suggest that "Two and twenty, now he’s rising" is a multiply-reversed way of saying "now he's rising 22". You suggest one possible interpretation, in which "rising" is equivalent to "on course for" (i.e. *heading towards* or *approaching*, in the same way a rising tide approaches the peak). Thus, Frederic is 21 and "rising" 22.

However, that interpretation seems unwieldy in the context of the lyrics. Here's the opening of the song:

> Pour, oh, pour the pirate sherry
> Fill, O fill the pirate glass!
> And, to make us more than merry
> Let the pirate bumper pass!
>
> For today our pirate 'prentice
> Rises from indenture freed
> Strong his arm, and keen his scent is
> He's a pirate now indeed!
>
> Here's good luck to Frederic's ventures!
> Frederic's out of his indentures
>
> Two and twenty, now he's rising
> And alone he's fit to fly
> Which we're bent on signalizing
> With unusual revelry.

Frederic is rising *from his indenture as a pirate* and (continuing the metaphor) is now *fit to fly alone*. "Two and twenty, now he's rising" means "He's 22 and now he's rising (to the level of full pirate)". It's a mistake to see "two and twenty" as the complement of "now he's rising"; instead, "now he's rising" is intended to be read with the next line – "now he's rising and alone he's fit to fly".

In Act II, you reference the song "When You Had Left Our Pirate Fold", which is a key turning point in the play. Without giving away the plot, it's sufficient to say that **the interpretation of Frederic's age is a critical matter**. Here's the relevant text:

> I'm afraid you don't appreciate the delicacy of your position
> You were apprenticed to us!
> [Frederic] Yes, until I reached my twenty-first year
> No, no, no
> Until you reached your twenty-first birthday!

Since everyone is unequivocal that Frederic had reached his twenty-first year (and therefore, they had all assumed, had completed his apprenticeship as a pirate), the only possible explanation for the earlier "two and twenty" reference is that **having turned 21, Frederic is now in his 22nd year.**

It's beyond the realms of possibility that "two and twenty" is a mistake. Perhaps [Sir William Schwenck Gilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._S._Gilbert) simply found the alliteration more appealing than "one and twenty"; or perhaps he was just being perverse.

Answer (score 0):

Neither - because of

> His birthday being on the 29th of February

there is a paradox and he is merely

> "Five, and a little bit over !"

And being pledged to serve till the age of 21, he will be

> 84 years old (21x4)

before he sees his 21st birthday.

The full text is in the Paradox song as per

> https://youtu.be/XXhJKzI1u48?t=112

Comment: Please pardon the use of spoilers, I didn't want to give away the plot points for those who don't already know them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really answers the question in the spirit that it's asked: it doesn't seem to resolve the question of whether the number of years since his birth is 21 or 22.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah you're right - other than showing he's really not either which is a plot element.  This could be a comment, but spoiler doesn't work there and is too long for a comment.

Comment: There's no need to use spoiler blocks here. [Site policy](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/3003) is that answers about specific works are expected to contain spoilers, and people who want to avoid being spoiled about a particular work can avoid answers to questions about that work.